# How do I navigate related entities from a stored procedure that is mapped to an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a complicated full-text search stored procedure that I have mapped to return an entity type. It won't allow me to navigate the references in the result though:

```
using (MyEntities kb = new MyEntities())
{
   var results = from customer in kb.SearchCustomers("blabla") select new 
   {
       CustomerName = customer.LastName + ", " + customer.FirstName,
       RegionName = customer.Region.Name
   };
}
```

This is throwing a null reference exception when referring to the customer.

Comment: LastName and FirstName work but Region doesn't? Make sure that SearchCustomers returns the expected data first.

Comment: Usually you need to call .Include("Region") when you are querying a normal table.  Perhaps you have to do the same when using a Stored proc?  Not sure I haven't started using stored procs yet :)

.............
var results = from customer in kb.SearchCustomers("blabla").Include("Region")...............

Answer (score 0):

We should check LastName and FirstName first. I think there are customers who don't have FirstName or Lastname.

```
using (MyEntities kb = new MyEntities())
{
   var results = from customer in kb.SearchCustomers("blabla") select new 
   {
       if(customer.LastName != null && customer.FirstName != null) 
       {
         CustomerName = customer.LastName + ", " + customer.FirstName,
         RegionName = customer.Region.Name
       }
   };
}
```